# Tape "test exited without ending" error with asynchronous forEach loops

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous, node.js-tape

### What I'm doing

#### Edit: I created a [repo](https://github.com/Mindcraft1/SO-Tape-test-exited-without-ending-error-with-asynchronous-forEach-loops) with a simplified version of my problem reproducing the issue.

I'm trying to set up automated frontend testings with [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/automate), [selenium-webdriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver) and [tape](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tape).

- [More about tape](https://ci.testling.com/guide/tape)

The idea is to define multiple browsers and devices which have to be tested one after another with X amount of given tests. In the example below I define only one test and two browsers on OSX.

In order to define the browsers only once and handle tests I created a repo `test-runner` which should be added as `dev-dependency` to the repos which need to be tested on the given devices and browsers.
The `test-runner` gets all needed tests passed, starts the first browser, runs the tests on that browser and once all tests are done the browser is closed `quit()` and the next browser gets started and tests again.

**test-runner**

*/index.js*

```
const webdriver = require( 'selenium-webdriver' )

// ---
// default browser configs
// ---
const defaults = {
  "os" : "OS X",
  "os_version" : "Mojave",
  "resolution" : "1024x768",
  "browserstack.user" : "username",
  "browserstack.key" : "key",
  "browserstack.console": "errors",
  "browserstack.local" : "true",
  "project" : "element"
}

// ---
// browsers to test
// ---
const browsers = [
  {
    "browserName" : "Chrome",
    "browser_version" : "41.0"
  },
  {
    "browserName" : "Safari",
    "browser_version" : "10.0",
    "os_version" : "Sierra"
  }
]

module.exports = ( tests, url ) => {

  // ---
  // Asynchronous forEach loop
  // helper function
  // ---
  async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
      await callback(array[index], index, array)
    }
  }

  // ---
  // runner
  // ---
  const run = async () => {

    // ---
    // Iterate through all browsers and run the tests on them
    // ---
    await asyncForEach( browsers, async ( b ) => {

      // ---
      // Merge default configs with current browser
      // ---
      const capabilities = Object.assign( {}, defaults, b )

      // ---
      // Start and connect to remote browser
      // ---
      console.info( '-- Starting remote browser hang on --', capabilities.browserName )
      const browser = await new webdriver.Builder().
        usingServer( 'http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub' ).
        withCapabilities( capabilities ).
        build()

      // ---
      // Navigate to page which needs to be checked (url)
      // ---
      console.log('-- Navigate to URL --')
      await browser.get( url )

      // ---
      // Run the tests asynchronously
      // ---
      console.log( '-- Run tests --- ' )
      await asyncForEach( tests, async ( test ) => {
        await test( browser, url, capabilities, webdriver )
      } )

      // ---
      // Quit the remote browser when all tests for this browser are done
      // and move on to next browser
      // Important: if the browser is quit before the tests are done
      // the test will throw an error beacause there is no connection
      //  anymore to the browser session
      // ---
      browser.quit()

    } )

  }

  // ---
  // Start the tests
  // ---
  run()

}
```

If you're wondering how this `asyncForEach` function works I got it from [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404).

**my-repo**

*/test/front/index.js*

```
const testRunner = require( 'test-runner' )
const url = ( process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' ) ? 'http://localhost:8888/element/...' : 'https://staging-url/element/...'

// tests to run
const tests = [
  require('./test.js')
]

testRunner( tests, url )
```

*/test/front/test.js*

```
const tape = require( 'tape' )

module.exports = async ( browser, url, capabilities, driver ) => {

  return new Promise( resolve => {

    tape( `Frontend test ${capabilities.browserName} ${capabilities.browser_version}`, async ( t ) => {

      const myButton = await browser.wait( driver.until.elementLocated( driver.By.css( 'my-button:first-of-type' ) ) )

      myButton.click()

      const marked = await myButton.getAttribute( 'marked' )
      t.ok(marked == "true", 'Button marked')

      //---
      // Test should end now
      //---
      t.end()

      resolve()

    } )

  })

}
```

*/package.json*

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=development node test/front/ | tap-spec",
    "travis": "NODE_ENV=travis node test/front/ | tap-spec"
  }
  ...
}
```

When I want to run the tests I execute `npm run test` in my-repo

Remember, that we have only one test (but could also be multiple tests) and two browsers defined so the behaviour should be:

1. Start browser 1 and navigate(Chrome)
2. One test on browser 1 (Chrome)
3. Close browser 1 (Chrome)
4. Start browser 2 and navigate (Safari)
5. One test on browser 2 (Safari)
6. Close browser 2 (Safari)
7. done

### The Problem

The asynchronous stuff seems to be working just fine, the browsers are started one after another as intended. **The problem is, that the first test does not finish even when i call `t.end()` and I don't get to the second test (fails right after 4.)**.

[image]

### What I tried

I tried using `t.pass()` and also running the CLI with `NODE_ENV=development tape test/front/ | tap-spec` but it didn't help.
I also noticed, that when I don't `resolve()` in `test.js` the test ends just fine but of course I don't get to the next test then.

I also tried to adapt my code like the solution from [this issue](https://github.com/substack/tape/issues/160) but didn't manage to get it work.

Meanwhile I also opened an [issue](https://github.com/substack/tape/issues/448) on tapes github page.

So I hope the question is not too much of a pain to read and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try replacing Safari with IE, Firefox or any other browser and run a test. Issue could be because Safari does not resolves http://localhost directly which causes problem.

Comment: the question is well written but it's a very specific issue that is hard to reproduce, not very easy to get an answer

Comment: @MukeshTiwari the problem is not because of safari

Comment: I think @mihai is on the right path but I didn't manage to get it work yet :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So unfortunately I got no answer yet with the existing setup and managed to  get the things work in a slightly different manner.

I figured out, that `tape()` processes can not `.end()` as long as any other proscess is running. In my case it was `browser`. So as long as the browser runs, I think `tape` can not end.

In my [example repo](https://github.com/Mindcraft1/SO-Tape-test-exited-without-ending-error-with-asynchronous-forEach-loops) there is no `browser` but something else must be still running in order to prevent `tape` to end.

So I had to define the tests in only one `tape` process. Since I managed to open the browsers in sequence and test it's totally fine for now.

If there are a lot of different things to test, i will just split these things in different files and import them into the main test file.

I also import the browser `capabilities` from a `dependency` in order to define them only once.

So here is the code:

*dependency main file*

```
{
  "browsers": [{
      "browserName": "Chrome",
      "browser_version": "41",
      "os": "Windows",
      "os_version": "10",
      "resolution": "1024x768",
      "browserstack.user": "username",
      "browserstack.key": "key"
    },
    }
      "browserName": "Safari",
      "browser_version": "10.0",
      "os": "OS X",
      "os_version": "Sierra",
      "resolution": "1024x768",
      "browserstack.user": "username",
      "browserstack.key": "key"
    }
  ]
}
```

*test.js*

```
const tape = require( "tape" )
const { Builder, By, until } = require( 'selenium-webdriver' );
const { browsers } = require( "dependency" )
const browserStack = 'http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub'

tape( "Browsers", async ( t ) => {

  await Promise.all( browsers.map( async ( capa ) => {

    const { browserName, browser_version, os } = capa

    const browser = new Builder().usingServer( browserStack ).withCapabilities( capa ).build();

    await browser.get( 'http://someurl.com' )

    const myButton = await browser.wait( until.elementLocated( By.css( 'my-button:first-of-type' ) ) )

    myButton.click()

    const marked = await myButton.getAttribute( 'marked' )

    t.ok(marked == "true", `${browserName} ${browser_version} ${os}`)

    await browser.quit()

  } ) )

  t.end()

} )
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like `tape` does not work so well with asynchronous code. See these discussions on their Github issues page:

https://github.com/substack/tape/issues/223
https://github.com/substack/tape/issues/160

The solutions seems to be to declare your tests with `tape.add` in the beginning, before any async code gets called.

I would also try to refactor some of that async code that might not be needed, if you're just opening browsers in a sequence.

Comment: Hi thx for your answer, i've read the issues you shared, but don't undertsand how to apply it to my setup. Could you write me an example if you have the time please?

Comment: I now tried to create a class with `.add()` function etc.. but I all the time end up having to do something async which confuses me even more. Tried 100 different approaches now and don't get it work. Would be really cool to get it work somehow, in another case I will have to define the browsers in each test, which I think must not be needed.

Comment: The thing with opening browsers in a sequence is, that I have to wait for the tests in order to quit the browser and start the next one (I think)

Comment: I would help but this setup is a bit heavy for me to try to install. I'll see if I can get something running with puppeteer instead of selenium

Comment: I understand. The thing is, that we used to use puppeteer and want to move to selenium since its explicitly integrated by browserstack. Had also async issues with puppeteer. I created a repo reproducing the issue, see my edit above.

Comment: Sorry it's me again, I simplified my repo with the showcase, no need for any browserstack account anymore now

Comment: Good morning @mihai and thx again for your help, unfortunately this doesn't resolves the problem, the important thing here is the moment at which `browser.quit()` is called. Like this it quits the browser before the tests are done, and the tests throw an error because the connection to the Browser session is already closed. I really have to make sure, that the active browser is only `quit` when all its tests work is done .

Comment: I updated the master with a log showing when the browser quits

Comment: you're right...I don't have any other ideas. You could try raising it on their github page, it could be a limitation of the library

Answer (score 0):

I would try to simplify how tests are written and executed first:

1. Have you tried running your tests using the tape binary? e.g. `tape test/front/test.js`
2. And at the same time simplify `test/front/test/js`: *(you'd have to figure out how to pass your parameters in an other way; perhaps you could hardcode them just for debugging purposes?)*

```
const tape = require( 'tape' )

tape( `your test outline`, ( t ) => {

  const alwaysEnd = () => t.end();

  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // your async stuff here...
    // resolve() or reject() at the end
  }).then(alwaysEnd, alwaysEnd);
})
```

Comment: Hi and thx for your answer, yes I did try the binary (didn't help), and hardcoding and starting a browser from inside a test works just fine. But I want to declare the browsers just ones from outside the tests this is the whole Idea.